# Laravel Login the user without email and password

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel-5

I have a URL say `http://myproj-com/trailer-video/_token`
Every time user hits the above URL, I want the user to log into my system. 
`_token` will be unique for each user and will be stored in users table.
Is there any way to login the user and get the user information in `auth()` object without providing email and password?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [`login`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#other-authentication-methods) function of `Auth` as:

```
Route::get('trailer-video/{token}', function($token) {
    $user = User::where('token', $token)->first();

    if($user) {
        auth()->login($user);
    }

    dd(auth()->user());
});
```

Comment: After loggin in, I need to redirect user to the auth protected page. It is returning me back to login

Comment: Make sure that `web` middleware is used for this route as it starts the session and also make sure that you have removed that `dd` from your code. That's just for example purpose.